# Cardinality of two Sylow $p$-subgroups is the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime number. Let $P,H$ be two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ such that there exists $g\in G$ for which $H\subset gPg^{-1}$ holds. Why should $|H|=|P|$? Does this follow from Lagrange?

I know that $|G|=[G:H]\cdot|H|$ and $|G|=[G:P]\cdot |P|$. I also know that $|P|=|gPg^{-1}|$.

**Definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup:**

If $P\leq G$ such $[G:P]\not\in p\mathbb{Z}$ and $|P|=p^{r}$ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$, then $P$ is called a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: By Sylow's theorems, unconditionally the cardinality of two Sylow $p$-subgroups is always the same, and there always exists such a $g$. It's unclear what you're assuming here.

Comment: I am trying to prove the Sylow theorems actually. So I cannot assume them.

Comment: What definition are you using of Sylow $p$-group?

Comment: How do you define a Sylow subgroup? Is it as a maximal $p$-subgroup?

Comment: I have included the definition which I have been given.

Comment: The definition of "$p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$" in the question amounts to saying that it's a subgroup whose order is the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$. So all $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ have the same order. (Note that this doesn't need any of the Sylow theorems, just the definition of Sylow subgroups.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H$ is contained in $gPg^{-1}$ but $|H|<|P|$, then by definition $H$ is not maximal. $gPg^{-1}$ is a larger $p$-subgroup containing $H$, so $H$ could not have been a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

This is with a Sylow subgroup defined as a maximal $p$-subgroup. It is easier with your definition; if the index is not a multiple of $p$, then the order is the maximum power of $p$ dividing $|G|$, so all Sylow subgroups have the same size regardless of the extra condition you provide.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Is there a way to show this with my definition?

Comment: @user764663 I edited. It's easier with your definition.